# Visually joining a button and text field in CSS

Tags: html, css

In a web forum I'm building (in Django/Python), one feature is that users can write a quick *single line* reply (tweet length) and then submit it for all participants to see. Currently, this is how I've laid out the simple form:

[image]

What changes should I make in my HTML/CSS to instead render my form as follows:

[image]

I'm looking for a fully responsive solution that's robust across all browsers, built in pure CSS.

---

My current code is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'home_reply' pk=link.l %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ replyform.description }}<br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Ignore the `{{}}` syntax - that's Django's template language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My technique to create something like that is to wrap both with a container

```
<div class="fancy-box-with-button">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

then move all your `<input>` styles to `.fancy-box-with-button` then make `<input>` transparent and other modifications as you see fit.

Make the button `position: absolute` and positioned right, add necessary `padding-right` to the parent element to prevent invisible input from being overlapped.

Most likely would look like this.

```
.fancy-box-with-button {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.fancy-box-with-button input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.fancy-box-with-button button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/wq2Lcv57/)

Comment: Are `input` and `button` nested within `.fancy-box-with-button` in your CSS example?

Comment: Yes, though actually it was a `SCSS` example, just updated my answer

Comment: also added a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/71m20atw/)
You should remove the `width: 1000px` since it will make the text field to wide, and it makes the text field not responsive.

Comment: In the demo, the submit button isn't conjoined with the character field. My requirements are somewhat more specialized.

Comment: Please include your code in your answer, not in an external link, SO snippets  (the `<>` button in the editor).