# Button inside input HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, button, input

I am trying create some input with button inside like here:

[image]

I read some tutorials and this code should work, but I don't know why it's not working.
Here's CSS:

```
#content input[class="small"] {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #909090;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#content button[type="submit"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  padding-right: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #23a298;
    border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
}
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/erxsqovh/

Comment: Are you using bootstrap

Comment: nope, I am writing all code

Comment: Use inline-block and relative position to position the button. Hope some already given the answers already. I suggest import bootstrap and use when necessary. It saves time. A lot of stuffs are pre written already

Comment: Please include your HTML in the question itself.... not an external ink. Better still use the `<>` button in the editor to create a SO snippet, which is like a fiddle, but embedded in the question.

Comment: For an alternate approach, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930419/visually-joining-a-button-and-text-field-in-css/45930510#comment78857720_45930510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `col-3>div has width 33%`. there is no space for the elements to fit. hence it goes to the next line. and that is a button next to input box not inside input box.

Use Media queries and width alongside for a better output.

```html
<input type=text><button>Submit</button>
```

Look at this one. there is no need to write special CSS to align button and input box.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KUBMgWDDvvtSOLu3NvaC?p=preview) for your code - fixed

Answer (score 0):

that is not a button inside an input but rather a button next to a input inside a div that is made to look like the input, You could achieve it by doing something like below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search-confirm").on('click', function(){
         var keyword = $("#search-field").val();
         alert("You searched - "+keyword)
    })
})
```

```css
.input-outer-padding {
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #3c0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input-inner-padding {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px 60px 5px 5px;
}

.input-field {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  /*resets for hiding the input boundaries */
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #3c0;
}

.search-confirm {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  background-color: #3c0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* here the magic begins */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.search-confirm:hover {
  background-color: #09f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-outer-padding">
  <div class="input-inner-padding">
    <input type="text" id="search-field" class="input-field" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
  <div class="search-confirm">SEARCH</div>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery/javascript is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @JonP the js was for a little fun, totally not relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

```css
#content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  height: 1080px;
}

#content .box-name {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #b4b4b4;
  margin-left:
}

#content .box {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

#content .item:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#content .item {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

#content label {
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  width:100%
}

#content input[type=text] {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #909090;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width:100%
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#content input::placeholder {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

#content input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #91d0cb;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
}

#content input[class="small"] {
   font-weight: 400;
    color: #909090;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
    padding-right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
}

#content button[type="submit"] {
     display: inline-block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 44px;
    top: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: #23a298;
    border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
}

#content input::placeholder {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}
.b{ position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex; }
#content input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #91d0cb;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: border-color 0.4s ease-out;
}

#content select[type=text] {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #909090;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#content button {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #23a298;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content button:hover {
  background-color: #22dccd;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: r 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#col-3 > div {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#col-3 div div {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#col-3 div div.b {
  margin: 0 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="square/red.css">
<body>
<section id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">
          <div id="col-sm-6">
            <div>
                <div>
                <label for="name">Person</label>
                    <div class="b">
                      <input class="small" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Type something...">
                      <button type="submit"></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

it right way i thinks